# Creating histogram plot with 2 arrays

Tags: r, histogram

How can I create a histogram with this data in R?

```
f = c('0-5', '6-10', '11-15', '16-20', '> 20')
counts_arr = c(0, 8, 129, 127, 173)
```

Right now, `counts_arr[0]` is associated with `f[0]`

So I am trying to get `f` to be on the X axis and `counts_arr` values on the Y axis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
barplot(counts_arr, names = f)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already a solution for this, but I had prepared something with `ggplot2` that I am posting nonetheless.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.4.3
library(forcats)
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.4.3

# dataframe provided
df <-
  base::cbind.data.frame(
    f = c('0-5', '6-10', '11-15', '16-20', '> 20'),
    counts_arr = c(0, 8, 129, 127, 173)
  )

# plot
ggplot2::ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = forcats::fct_inorder(f), y = counts_arr)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "f", y = "count")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-02-10 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).