# Histogram or BarPlot from dataset columns in R language

Tags: r, csv, histogram

INPUT: I have a CSV separated by comma, where in columns there are ages from 0 to 100 years and a second row with the total population by age. There are more rows, but with data that is not relevant in this case.

[image]

OUTPUT: I want to create a histogram in R language where in x-axis shows the ages of the people, and y-axis shows total population of those age.

I have a little code, that read a csv file and show the part of csv file that I want to represented.

````
```{r}
v_file <- "../20181022_Ejercicio_1/DATASET.csv"
data <- read.csv(file=v_file, sep=',', header = TRUE)

edades <- data[1,2:101]
edades
```
````

[image]

That table shows the total population vs age.

More information of my dataset...

```
dput(edades[, 1:50])
structure(list(X0 = 13633L, X1 = 13918L, X2 = 13712L, X3 = 13533L, 
    X4 = 14018L, X5 = 13968L, X6 = 13801L, X7 = 13747L, X8 = 14288L, 
    X9 = 13588L, X10 = 13849L, X11 = 13612L, X12 = 13630L, X13 = 13456L, 
    X14 = 13118L, X15 = 12776L, X16 = 13284L, X17 = 13213L, X18 = 13051L, 
    X19 = 13771L, X20 = 13903L, X21 = 14450L, X22 = 15543L, X23 = 16714L, 
    X24 = 18644L, X25 = 19330L, X26 = 20726L, X27 = 21812L, X28 = 22323L, 
    X29 = 22801L, X30 = 23531L, X31 = 23952L, X32 = 24602L, X33 = 25041L, 
    X34 = 25887L, X35 = 26276L, X36 = 26918L, X37 = 26872L, X38 = 27608L, 
    X39 = 27503L, X40 = 27756L, X41 = 27653L, X42 = 26994L, X43 = 26239L, 
    X44 = 25364L, X45 = 24818L, X46 = 24194L, X47 = 23432L, X48 = 23152L, 
    X49 = 23074L), .Names = c("X0", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", 
"X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10", "X11", "X12", "X13", "X14", "X15", 
"X16", "X17", "X18", "X19", "X20", "X21", "X22", "X23", "X24", 
"X25", "X26", "X27", "X28", "X29", "X30", "X31", "X32", "X33", 
"X34", "X35", "X36", "X37", "X38", "X39", "X40", "X41", "X42", 
"X43", "X44", "X45", "X46", "X47", "X48", "X49"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717382/creating-histogram-plot-with-2-arrays/48717733#48717733

Comment: `hist(t(edades[1, ]))`. Transposing with `t()` can turns a row into a column, and a column is just a normal vector we can work with.

Comment: @RyanD the problem is that my dataset is columns inverted. Is not a typical histogram of one parameter... I have 100 parameters in x-axies!

Comment: You can make a row into a numeric vector with `as.numeric(edades[1,])`. Then do `barplot(as.numeric(df[1,]))`, and optionally add a vector of names.

Comment: Mmm, after your comment and reading a little more closely, I think your're confusing a histogram with a barplot. What you're describing is a barplot. A histogram has a single continuous variable on the x-axis and shows it's density on the y axis. A barplot has a categorical variable on the x axis (possibly a binned continuous variable) and shows counts or some other summary variable on the y axis.

Comment: @Gregor ok! But in x-axies I would like to have 100 parts corresponding each part of the age of population... In your solution I only have 6 parts... I don't understand the graph results!

Comment: @Gregor mmm.. probably yes... And do you know how can I represented?

Comment: Can you share some data reproducibly in your question? Images are pretty useless because I can't copy/paste and get it into R. Sharing `dput(edades[, 1:50])` as a sample would be really helpful. It will be a copy/pasteable version of the first 50 columns of your R object.

Comment: @RyanD when I paste your solution of barplot, appears this Error: Error in df[1, ] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Ryan is using `df` as a common stand-in for the name of a data frame. Replace his `df` with your `edades`.

Comment: @Gregor how can I paste my dataset (csv file) here? Has it helped you what I add now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181970/discussion-between-anna-castan-and-gregor).

Comment: Enter `dput(edades[, 1:50])` into R, copy and paste the result into your question. We don't need your CSV, we need your R object. `dput` is the best way to share it.

Comment: @Gregor I opened a discussion in chat, moreover I update the question with more information about dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your data to something usual (in columns, not rows):

```
age_df = data.frame(t(edades), as.numeric(sub("X", "", names(edades))))
names(age_df) = c("n", "age")
```

Plot with base:

```
barplot(height = age_df$n, names.arg = age_df$age)
```

[image]

Or plot with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(age_df, aes(x = age, y = n)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]